# A sufficient (?) condition under which a linear order is order-isomorphic to a subset of the real line

Tags: order-theory

Let $(\mathbb{X},<)$ be a linear order. Assume that there exists $g:\mathbb{X} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for each fixed $x<x'$ the function $y \mapsto g(x,y)-g(x',y)$ is a strictly increasing bijection of $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself.

I am trying to prove (or disprove) that then $(\mathbb{X},<)$ is necessarily order-isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual order. That is, there exists a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know that every finite or countably infinite linear ordering is order isomorphic to a subset of the rationals? I haven't given much thought to your actual question, so if this result is well known to you and doesn't seem relevant, then ignore my comment.

Comment: Is it even straightforward that $|X|\le|\Bbb R|$?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, thank you. Yes, I know this fact, but I don't know how to use it to prove (or disprove) the statement of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $F\colon\Bbb X\to \Bbb R$ as
$$F(x)=g(x,0)-g(x,1).$$

**Claim.** Then $x<x'$ implies $F(x)<F(x')$.

*Proof.*
Let $h(y)=g(x,y)-g(x',y)$. We are given that $h\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is strictly increasing.
Now we have $$F(x')-F(x)=g(x',0)-g(x',1)-g(x,0)+g(x,1)=h(1)-h(0)>0$$
as desired. $\square$

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!